# Convert KAFKA json message to case class and save it to Cassandra using RDD approach using play json

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I am new to Spark streaming .And Here is my Requirement:
I have a json of below format:

```
{"brand":"blowfish","category":"shoes","description":"Blowfish Women's Hiro Whiskey Dcpu Ankle-high Synthetic Sandal - 8m","mode":"visa signature","orditems":"3","productcode":"404e242a-070f-4fbb-a271-489c92049b05","unitprice":"7630"}
```

Now my project requirement is to using Play json and RDD approach i have to store it to a cassandra table .Table:transction_table. keyspace:krios
.I  am able to achieve it using data frame.But as per design we have to follow RDD approach and case class.

Can you please hellp.After converting the json to Case class I am not getting "saveToCassandra" methos.

Here is my sample code:

```
import TransctionCoreClass.TransctionData
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DoubleType, StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.{ConsumerStrategies, KafkaUtils}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.{JsPath, Json, Reads, Writes}

object TransctionCoreRDDFormat {


  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
  Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010").setLevel(Level.OFF)
 case class TransctionData(productcode:String,description:String,brand:String,category:String,unitprice:String,orditems:String,mode:String)

  val transactionSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("brand", StringType, true),
    StructField("category", StringType, true),
    StructField("description", StringType, true),
    StructField("mode", StringType, true),
    StructField("ordItems", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("productCode", StringType, true),
    StructField("unitPrice", StringType, true)))

  val spark = SparkSession.builder
    .master("local")
    .appName("TransctionReceiver")
    .getOrCreate();
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(30))
  import spark.implicits._

  ssc.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
  val topics = List("-first_topic")
  val configuration = Configuration.apply(ConfigFactory.load.resolve)
  val productStreanm=
    KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, PreferConsistent, ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String,String](topics,buildKafkaProperties(configuration)))

  productStreanm.foreachRDD{
    rddRaw=>{
      println("Entrringgg")
      val transrdd = rddRaw.map(x=>convertToCaseClass(x.value().toString))
 ===============Now how to store it in cassandra?????============ as I am  not getting option to saveToCassnadra method available as part of transrdd.






    }


  }




  implicit val transctionReads:Reads[TransctionData]={
    (

      ( JsPath \ "brand").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "category").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "description").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "mode").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "ordItems").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "productCode").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "unitPrice").read[String]

      )(TransctionData.apply _)
  }

  implicit val transctionFormat:Writes[TransctionData]=new Writes[TransctionData]{
    def writes(trns: TransctionData)=Json.obj(
      "brand" -> JsString(trns.brand),
      "category" -> JsString(trns.category),
      "description" -> JsString(trns.description),
      "mode" -> JsString(trns.mode),
      "ordItems" -> JsString(trns.orditems),
      "productCode" -> JsString(trns.productcode),
      "unitPrice" -> JsString(trns.unitprice)

    )
  }

  val cassnadraConnector=CassandraConnector(
    ssc.sparkContext.getConf
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","localhost")
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port","9042")
      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username","cassandra")
      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password","cassandra")
  )

  def buildKafkaProperties(configuration: Configuration)=Map (

    "bootstrap.servers" -> configuration.kafka.brokerList,
    "key.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
    "value.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
    "auto.offset.reset" ->"earliest",
    "offset" ->"20",
    //"max.poll.records"->20,
    //  "enable.auto.commit" ->false,
    "group.id" ->"grou1pu774u77i3u8"
  )


  def convertToCaseClass(data:String):Option[TransctionData]= {


    val parsedJsValue = Json.parse(data)
    val parsed = Json.fromJson[TransctionData](parsedJsValue)
    parsed
    parsed match{

      case s @ JsSuccess(_,_) => s.asOpt
      case e :JsError         =>None

    }

  }


  ssc.start()
  // println(s"==========Spark context Sarted ]======${ssc.sparkContext.appName}")
  ssc.awaitTermination()










}
```

Comment: Can you use Spark Structured Streaming instead?

Comment: Hi Alex..If you can share some sample code on how to do this?

Comment: We are supposed to use RDD approach with json play franework..That is the technical requirement

Comment: for example: https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/spark-dse/src/main/scala/com/datastax/alexott/streaming/StructuredStreamingKafkaDSE.scala#L30 - if you use structured streaming, your code is much more simple & optimized than when you use RDDs